# Splitting a string in vb.net (no delimiters)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, split

First time making a game, and I'm loading in the map form an xml file.
Each row is literally a row that comes up on the screen.

Example string: 0000010020111030010000002130000101000...
I need something to split each of those numbers into an array - so that one number is one item in the array; to be able to print the map.

I tried using this but I quickly figured out that I need delimiters "," and such.

```
    Dim t() As String 'temp array
    Dim wordl1aXtemp As String 'the very long string of numbers
    For j = 0 To 1
        For i = 0 To 41
            wordl1aXtemp = wordl1aX(j, i)
            t = wordl1aXtemp.Split("") 'temp array loaded
        Next
        j += 1
    Next
```

I already have the map designed, and its going to be a pain going back to put a thousand or so ",".

How can I break up a long chain of numbers into an array where each character is 1 item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want string.char().   A string is nothing more than an array of characters. You can access each character of the string by calling the char method with a specific index.

```
 Dim test As String = "Today"
 x = test.char(3) 'Will give you "a"
```

Comment: Thanks. I just found that using x = test.ToCharArray works too, and better

Comment: But you'll do that conversion 84 times

Comment: Yes, you already have an array, no need to create one.  As the guy below said, you can just use the string.

Comment: Using `.char(3)` gives me an error:  _BC30456: 'char' is not a member of 'String'_  Perhaps you meant `.Chars(3)`  You don't need `.Chars()` anyway.  Just `test(3)` will do.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you can't just use the string itself? https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/microsoft.visualbasic.strings.getchar(v=vs.110).aspx

(Basically a string is just an array of characters)

Comment: Well, I'm checking each number in an array to print the tiles. So 0 is the ground tile where 1 is the wall. I'm also planning to use the array for collisions, so I highly doubt it.